# How read value from XmlNode

Tags: c#

I have a Xml file and I try to read value from node `Ticket`, but my output is still empty. Can somebody help me ?

Xml docmunet :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Header>
<TicketHeader xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<Ticket>
heslo
</Ticket>
</TicketHeader>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<test xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"/>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My code :

```
     doc= new XmlDocument();
     doc.Load(path);
     XmlNode temp = doc.SelectSingleNode("//Ticket");
     textBox3.Text=temp.InnerXml;
```

Comment: solution is :


             XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
             nsmgr.AddNamespace("ab", "http://tempuri.org/");

             XmlNode temp = doc.SelectSingleNode("//ab:Ticket", nsmgr);

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the wrong path to the node you want and use '.InnerText'.  Here is the corrected code:

```
 doc= new XmlDocument();
 doc.Load(path);
 string ticket = doc.SelectSingleNode("//TicketHeader/Ticket").InnerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

this will be the correct for your requirement
   doc= new XmlDocument();
     doc.Load(path);
     XmlNode temp = doc.SelectSingleNode("//TicketHeader/Ticket");
     textBox3.Text=temp.InnerXml;
thanks,

KRG